# Array of [Any] and contains()

Tags: swift, enumeration

I'm trying to test if an array of type `[Any]` contains a value of a specific  type (say, `Int`).

I'm aware that Swift does not know how to compare an `Int` and a value of arbitrary type, and I guess that's what's being expressed in the autocomplete template:

`contains(predicate: (protocol<>) throws -> Bool)`

So I tried this code:

```
let intValue:Int = 5 // for example

let isContained = myArrayOfAny.contains({ element in 
    return ((element as? Int) == intValue)
})
```

...and it compiles (can't make sure it works yet); but still can't make heads or tails of the `predicate: (protocol<>)` part. What does it mean? The documentation for `SequenceType` is quite cryptic:

```
contains(_: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
 Default Implementation
Return true iff an element in self satisfies predicate.

Declaration
@warn_unused_result func contains(@noescape _ predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
```

---

**EDIT:** I'm quite confused because, all search results I've seen have the `contains()` method of `Array` as just taking the value to be tested for containment, e.g.:

```
if myArrayOfInt.contains(someInt){
    ...
```

and not a closure.

Comment: You may have to loop through the array, and for each element, if casting that object to an Int is successful, compare. If equal, return true. Otherwise, continue to next element.

Comment: I know, that straigh-forward method is guaranteed to work. However, it doesn't sound very Swift-y...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two different `contains()` methods (both protocol
extensions to `SequenceType`). The first one is

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
    /// Return `true` iff `element` is in `self`.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func contains(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool
}
```

and it requires that the sequence elements conform to the `Equatable`
protocol, which guarantees that they can be compared with `==`:

```
public protocol Equatable {
    // ...
    public func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}
```

For example, in

```
let intValue:Int = 5
let myArrayOfInt = [4, 5, 6]
let isContained = myArrayOfInt.contains(intValue)
```

you have an array of `Int`, and `Int` conforms to `Equatable`,
so this `contains()` method can be used to check for the presence
of a certain element.

This does not work for

```
let myArrayOfAny : [Any] = [4, 5, 6]
```

because `Any` does not conform to `Equatable`. Here you can use
the second `contains()` method

```
extension SequenceType {
    /// Return `true` iff an element in `self` satisfies `predicate`.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func contains(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
}
```

which takes a *predicate*, i.e. a boolean function. Instead of 
comparing with `==`, the predicate is applied to each array element.
This method does not require that the array elements are `Equatable`.

And that's what you do in

```
let myArrayOfAny : [Any] = [4, 5, 6]
let intValue:Int = 5 // for example
let isContained = myArrayOfAny.contains({ element in 
    return ((element as? Int) == intValue)
})
```

This will yield `true` if any array element can be cast to an `Int`
and is equal to the given `intValue`.

The might see the first method more frequently but the second
is far more general, e.g.

```
if myArrayOfCustomObjects.contains ({ $0.someProperty == "foo" })
```

or

```
if myArrayOfInts.contains ({ $0 > 17 })
```

So the first `contains()` is a kind of specialization of the second one for a simple containment check in arrays of equatable elements. It *could* be implemented as

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Equatable {

    public func contains(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool {
        return self.contains({ $0 == element } )
    }
}
```

You'll find the same with `indexOf()` which also comes in
two flavors:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
    // ...
    public func indexOf(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Self.Index?
}

extension CollectionType {
    // ...
    public func indexOf(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self.Index?
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your through answer; very enlightening.

Comment: So, there is no simple, non-duplicating way to check if the value of a variable defined as `Any` (`Int`, `String` or `Bool`) is contained in an array of type `[Any]`, but that is guaranteed at runtime to contain values **of the same type** as the variable?