# Testing array containment for values defined as Any, but guaranteed to be of the same type.

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics, equatable

Building on [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34081580/433373) (and the accepted answer), I want to test containment of a value in an array.

The value is stored in a variable defined as of type `Any`, and the array is defined as `[Any]`.

The actual types of the value stored in the variable and the elements in the array are decided at runtime, but are guaranteed to satisfy the following conditions:

1. Both types (variable and array elements) coincide, and
2. They are either one of `String`, `Int` or `Bool`.

So far, I got this code working:

```
var isContained = false

if let intValue = anyValue as? Int {
    isContained = arrayOfAny.contains({element in return ((element as? Int) == intValue)})
}
else if let stringValue = anyValue as? String {
    isContained = arrayOfAny.contains({element in return ((element as? String) == stringValue)})
}
else if let boolValue = anyValue as? Bool {
    isContained = arrayOfAny.contains({element in return ((element as? Bool) == boolValue)})
}
```

However, there is a lot of logic duplication and I wish I could make it smarter, perhaps something like this:

```
isContained = arrayOfAny.contains({element in 
    return ((element as? Equatable) == (anyValue as? Equatable))
})
```

...but the restrictions on the use of the protocol `Equatable` stand in the way. Any advice?

Comment: Can you not just use `arrayOfAny.filter({$0 as anyValue.dynamicType})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now what you are trying to do. Here is an example of how you can make it working

```
let arrayOfAny:[AnyObject] = [1,7,9,true, "string"]
func getAny(value:AnyObject) -> [AnyObject]{
    return self.arrayOfAny.filter ({$0 === value})
}
```

The above function will return an array of matches which ideally should be a single result or empty array.

Example:

```
self.getAny(1) // [1]
self.getAny(0) // []
```

You can also modify it to simply return a Bool

```
func getAny(value:AnyObject) -> Bool{
  return self.arrayOfAny.filter ({$0 === value}).count > 0
}
```

Example:

```
self.getAny(1) // true
self.getAny(0) // false
```

**Edit:**

As Martin R mentioned this would not always work. Unfortunately I didn't fully tested it before I post this answer. After playing with this for a while I came up with very similar approach to the one NicolasMiari has:

```
let arrayOfAny:[AnyObject] = [1,Int.max,9,true, "string"]
func getAny(anyValue:AnyObject) -> [AnyObject]{
    return self.arrayOfAny.filter ({
         var exist:Bool
         switch anyValue.self{
            case is String: exist = $0 as? String == anyValue as? String
                break
            case is Int: exist = $0 as? Int == anyValue as? Int
                break
            case is Bool: exist = $0 as? Bool == anyValue as? Bool
                break
            default: exist = false
            }
            return exist
     })
```

}

The downside of this approach is that the `int 1` and `true` will be returned when calling `self.getAny(1)` the result will be `[1,1]` as `1` and `true` can be successfully casted to both `Int` and `Bool` and not as probably intended to just return `[1]`.
In other words if you just have `true` in your array without having `Int 1` you will still get positive result as if it was existing in your array. Same works the other way around as well.

Comment: This is not reliable. In your `arrayOfAny`, all elements are converted to NSNumber or NSString instances, and `===` is *pointer* equality, not value equality. This may work as intended or not. As an example, with `let arrayOfAny:[AnyObject] = [1,Int.max,9,true, "string"]`  both `print(getAny(true))` and `print(getAny(Int.max))` return an empty array in my test.